# On with salesforceThe public key certificate used for Single Sign.com (Community) (http://www.salesforce.com) will expire email

Tags: community, security, single-sign-on

I received this email and I understand that we need to install a new public key certificate. However, I'm not sure where to start and how to do this. Can someone please shed some light?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your Salesforce org go to setup and search Auth provider and generate the certificate from there and then use this certificate in other Salesforce instance or whenever you are using this single sign on service.

Or if you are doing SSO in to the Salesforce from your external server then you need to generate certificate from your external server and then in `SF setup search > single sign on` setting and then edit existing setting and update this new certificate.

Comment: Hi Tushar! Thanks for responding. I did try checking Setup > Security Controls > Auth. Providers but its blank. So I assume we're not using the SSO to any apps. 

At this point, I guess I would need to know if  were doing SSO in to the Salesforce from an external server.

I also check Setup> Identity Provider and its blank.

Sorry I'm really don't know where to start.

Comment: Also, what I'm sure is the certificate that's going to expire. I can see it when you go to Setup > Security Controls > Certificate and Key Management. It's a Self-Signed Certificate. Do I need to create a new one for that?

Comment: @gieAdkins yes you need to generate that. You can easily check from where this certificate came.